# Adblock Plus - Clear Cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching, adblock

I am building a adblock plus list and while testing it I find it hard for adblock plus to update properly.

1. I added a domain to exclude @@||
2. Saw it was not blocked
3. Removed it again
4. Still not blocked

So I am thinking there must be an internal cache I need to clear in Addblock Plus. I am using Chrome. I tried to restart Chrome and clear the Chrome cache (right click refresh).

Any ideas?

Comment: It'd be great if you could report this issue [in the Adblock Plus issue tracker](https://issues.adblockplus.org/). Especially reliable reproduction steps and information on the browser and extension versions would be quite handy to quickly find and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out if you go to the following it works

Chrome Settings > Clear Browserdata > Clear images and files

Comment: Feel free to correct me but doesn't this also get rid of all the settings in Adblock Plus? If so, simply reinstalling the extension should have the same effect.